# Help identifying shower valve in older home

Tags: plumbing, shower, valve

We've run into a shower valve we can't identify. Does anyone have any idea what this is or who made it? The house was built in the 60's and we aren't sure that this is original, but it could be. There is some white paint on the valve body, but we think there is a B or an 8 imprinted on the metal you can barely see in the white paint. The cartridge doesn't come out, unless you unscrew the 2 side screws, which we are reluctant to do until we can get some replacement parts in hand.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer for myself- it is an 1960s era american standard...0061. Figured I'd post the answer here in case someone else had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an American Standard Push-Pull. There's a few different styles but you can still find replacement parts for it online.

Comment: thank you very much for your help!